# Is Matthew 27:52 an allusion to 2 Kings 13:21?

Tags: matthew, 2-kings, intertextuality

> [Mat 27:49-53 KJV] 49 The rest said, Let be, let us see whether Elias [IE: Elijah] will come to save him. 50  Jesus, when he had cried again with a loud voice, **yielded up the ghost**. 51 And, behold, the veil of the temple was rent in twain from the top to the bottom; and the earth did quake, and the rocks rent; 52 **And the graves were opened; and many bodies of the saints which slept arose, 53 And came out of the graves after his resurrection, and went into the holy city, and appeared unto many**.
>
> [2Ki 13:21 KJV] 21 And it came to pass, as they were burying a man, that, behold, they spied a band [of men]; and they cast the man into the sepulchre of Elisha: and when the man was let down, and touched the bones of Elisha, he revived, and stood up on his feet.

If so it is slightly altered in that Elisha was already in the place of the dead but when the dead touched his bones they lived whereas Jesus enters the realm of the dead later.

Would it be too far fetched to imagine that Elisha was among the "zombies"? That would mak

Regardless, like Elijah, Christ has "life in himself":

> [Jhn 5:26 KJV] 26 For as the Father hath life in himself; so hath he given to the Son to have life in himself;

Comment: That is interesting, because they were resurrected 3 days before Christ was. I am thinking that after He gave up the Ghost, they were legally free because the blood had been spilt, and the ransom paid. (Zech. 9:11 As for thee also, by the blood of thy covenant I have sent forth thy prisoners out of the pit wherein is no water.)

Answer (score 0):

If Matt 27:52 is alluding to 2 Kings 13:21, it is not a literary allusion as there is little in common except a resurrection.  Most commentators ( plus myself) find the incident in 2 Kings 13:21 puzzling for a variety of reasons that do not matter here.

However, the idea of a resurrection is not enough to make a parallel nor an allusion else all would be.  In this case the differences are too great.

- In Matt the resurrected have been buried - in Kings the dead man was not buried
- In Matt the resurrected have been dead for some time - in Kings the man had been dead for a very short time without even a funeral
- In Matt the resurrected come to life as result of Messiah's death - in Kings the dead man is revived as a result of touching a prophet's bones
- In Matt the resurrected are raised to witness of God's power - in Kings the dead man rises to fight again